# Bezier Curve - Edit Mode - how does the Spin menu item work?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

When you create a Bezier curve and enter the Edit mode, then you will see a greyed out menu item Spin in the Curve menu in the header.

How do i activate this menu item? How does it work?

[image]

Comment: I don't know, but it seems a python-only tool, which maybe in the future will have a working ui entry. maybe. I found a reference to bpy.ops.curve.spin in https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78a_release/bpy.ops.curve.html

Comment: Well, the same tool also exists for Surface. And here it is not greyed out. It spins the surface curve around the 3d cursor then. I am just curious why it is greyed out for a Bezier curve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason Spin is greyed out is because currently the UI file for that menu item is

```
layout.operator("curve.spin")
```

Which points to an operator written in C

**source/blender/editors/curve/editcurve.c**

```
void CURVE_OT_spin(wmOperatorType *ot)
```

Inside that operator is a poll to check if the current state of blender warrants showing the menu entry as clickable.

```
ot->poll = ED_operator_editsurf;
```

this sets the value of `ot->poll` to whatever the value of `ED_operator_editsurf` is,

**source/blender/editors/screen/screen_ops.c**

```
int ED_operator_editsurf(bContext *C)
{
    Object *obedit = CTX_data_edit_object(C);
    if (obedit && obedit->type == OB_SURF)
        return NULL != ((Curve *)obedit->data)->editnurb;
    return 0;
}
```

this tests if the object is in edit mode, it would be, and also tests the `type` of the object, which in that case is not `OB_SURF`, not a surface type curve.